# Changing multiple outputted calendar format

Tags: php

I have some dates that are outputted by previous javascript and into a hidden text fields.

I need to convert it to another format ( dd/mm/yyyy ) and am not quite sure how to do it.

The values are dynamic so im not sure how many there will be so i guess it will need to run through a loop maybe?

I need to convert this

```
Wed Jan 19 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST),Thu Jan 20 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST),Fri Jan 21 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST),Sat Jan 22 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST),Sun Jan 23 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
```

to

```
19/01/2011,20/01/2011,21/01/2011,22/01/2011,23/01/2011
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = 'Wed Jan 19 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST),Thu Jan 20 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST),Fri Jan 21 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST),Sat Jan 22 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST),Sun Jan 23 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)';

$dates = explode(',', $str);
$result = array();
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $result[] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
}
echo implode(',', $result);
```

Also, note that this code depends on the local timezone. So if your timezone isn't `GMT+11`, then you can change it with `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Canberra');` for example

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("Wed Jan 19 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$str='Wed Jan 19 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)';
$t=strtotime($str);
echo strftime('%d/%m/%Y', $t);
```

Note however that [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) will use the system timezone to convert the time - I'm in the UK and this time, when coverted to GMT, would actually display '18/01/2011'. Just something to be aware of! From the manual:

> Every call to a date/time function
> will generate a E_NOTICE if the time
> zone is not valid, and/or a E_STRICT
> or E_WARNING message if using the
> system settings or the TZ environment
> variable. See also
> [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [explode](http://php.net/explode) it and then use the [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) function.